# unable to set permission read and write to volumes directory in macos 10.15

Tags: applescript, sh

i wanted to set the read and write permission to volumes directory i have tried with apple script.
its adding that user in ACL but permission getting set to custom.
if i use chown its  sets the permission to read and write but i don't want to change ownership of that directory just wanted to add user to that directory with read and write access
here is my code

```
code with chown 

set userName to "test"
set folderPath to "/Volumes/"
set scriptName to "/Users/test/Desktop/mk.sh"
do shell script "chown  " & quoted form of userName & " " & quoted form of folderPath with administrator privileges
do shell script scriptName

In this above i am able to set permission read and write but its changing owner from system to test i don't want to change owner

code with chmod

set userName to "test"
set folderPath to "/Volumes/"
set scriptName to "/Users/test/Desktop/mk.sh"
do shell script "chmod -R +a \"" & userName & " allow read,write\" " & quoted form of folderPath with administrator privileges
do shell script scriptName
```

After running code which chmod its add user to ACL but unable to set permission read and write its sets to custom[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tix8.png)

i wanted to set read and write access to user "test" without changing the ownership of that particular directory.

Comment: Yes, `chown` changes the owner, that is what it does, and the "custom" permissions are the ACL you added.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Note that it may not be wise to mess with system directories if you don't know about the shell commands you are using.

Comment: I want user  gets add in volumes directory with read and write access . Also  i am aware its not recommended to mess with system directories so  i am using this cmds on my testing machine

Comment: An ACL entry should do that, but _what are you actually trying to do_ (other than adding read/write permissions)?

Comment: We have one mounting script which helps us for user level mounting in macos 12.7 so as Apple disable user level mounting from Monterey os For OMFS file system  so our script create directory using mkdir command but to do that we need to give read n write permission manually to that particular user so i want that permission giving part should be done with script